# Using Func<T,TResult> c#

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I am working on PCL which along with a lot of functionality also provides log in. Also I recently started using delegates.

### The Current Case:

I have a Simple methods that takes in parameters and provide GPlus, Facebook or Simple logIn with Username and Password. as in the code below:

```
public async Task<SignInResponse> SignInUsingFacebook(IFacebookInitializer faceBookConfiguration)
{
   //my code
}
public async Task<SignInResponse> SignInUserNameAndPass(string username,string password)
{
   //my code
}
public async Task<SignInResponse> SignInUsingGPlus(IGPlusInitializer gPlusConfiguration)
{
   //my code
}
```

This is great, I can call them from my application directly and handle data but,
I recently came across `Delegates` and `Func<T,TResult>`

### What I want to do:

I want a simple method that takes in a parameter an enum of `LogInType` as below:

```
public enum LogInType
{
    UserNameAndPassword,
    Facebook,
    GooglePlus,
}
```

and based on the type of login type provided to the method, handles the LogIn process on it's own and just returns the `SignInResponse` object.

---

Is there a way this can be done using Delegates. Rather than having 3 individual methods to call for each case. If yes, then can someone please help in the parameters to be passed to the Single method along with The LogInType. I know it has to be a `Func` but what would the `Func` look like as it has to take 3 different parameters.

---

**As From the Comments:**

Each of those methods is a different signature anyway so you have a  `Func<IFacebookInitializer`, `Task<SignInResponse>>`, `Func<string, string, Task<SignInResponse>>` and `Func<IGPlusInitializer, Task<SignInResponse>>` so you'd still end up with an if statement.

Can I return a Func when the method is called? this ways I can return either of the three func based on a quick switch case. The issue would be (if it's possible) what would be the generic response (or the common response) type of the method that returns either of these three methods

Comment: Instead of passing an enum and scrambling to get the parameters into the method, why not create an abstract Parameters class and subclass it for each of the three login variants?

Comment: Each of those methods is a different signature anyway so you have a `Func<IFacebookInitializer, Task<SignInResponse>>`, `Func<string, string, Task<SignInResponse>>` and `Func<IGPlusInitializer, Task<SignInResponse>>` so you'd still end up with an if statement.

Comment: @Kempeth I did try it, it just doesn't make a huge difference as compared to Func when I came across it.

Comment: @DavidG Can I return a Func when the method is called? this ways I can return either of the three `func` based on a quick switch case. The issue would be  (if it's possible) what would be the generic response (or the common response) type of the method that returns either of these three methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The generic Func works as follows:
The last datatype that you define in Func - "output" in this case should be the return type of the method which you are going to that particular function and the method should also be static. 
This might help:

```
Func<LogInType, string> Login = LoginMethod;

private static string LoginMethod(LogInType loginType)
{
    if (loginType == LogInType.Facebook)
        return "Facebook";
    if (loginType == LogInType.GooglePlus)
        return "GooglePlus";
    if (loginType == LogInType.UserNameAndPassword)
        return "UserNameAndPassword";
    return "Default";
}
```

The return type in the above example is string just for explaining.

Comment: How am I supposed to passIn Parameters? like username or password or IFacebook or IGPlus?

Comment: You can declare a common parent interface (for ex: ILoginDetails) with username and password. Inherit this interface for each of your interfaces and pass the same as an input.
You can add n number of parameters to your func:
Func<param1, param2, param3, param4, outputParam>

Comment: So a Func<ILogInInputParameters,SignInResponse> LogIn = LoginMethod where `ILogInInputParameters` must have a property named `LogInType`? Is that what you mean? and then use `is` and check for the three possible case scenarios

Comment: You can do that if you like, I would suggest the following:
Func<ILogInInputParameters, LogInType, SignInResponse>
It is better to keep the LogInType as a separate parameter because the login parameters have nothing to do with the login type.

Comment: So it'll be just a blank interface

Comment: Why will it be a blank interface? it will contain Username and Password properties; you can also add other common properties which you wish to use, I gave a suggestion for your problem, how to design the solution is up to you. Thanks!

Comment: Please be advised There are no common properties. The Username and Password are only required for Normal logIn and not Facebook or GooglePlus. For Facebook, you have to pass in the app ID and the dev ID where as for google there is a different case scenario

Comment: Then instead of creating an interface for the parameters, create a parent class LoginParameters with Username, Password, IFacebookInitializer and IGPlusInitializer. This way there is no contract inheritance, just a simple wrapper class for parameters.

Comment: Can my LogInMethod return a Func instead? Like public Func<T,TResult> FetchLogInMethod(LogInType TypeOfLogIn){} and can be called as var del = FetchLogInMethod(LogInType.Facebook); and then fire up the del like del();

Comment: It can return a Func as a return type, but why complicate things? You will have to return 3 different funcs in total. Keep it as simple as possible, it is not going to make a huge difference.

Comment: can you share a sample for that as well? It'll be of great help

Comment: I think you should just simply write a single Func<> or even a simple class method with the return type that you want, LoginParameters and LogInType will be the parameters for that method and write a switch case inside it based on LogInType and execute accordingly, returning Func for no reason will make things complicated unnecessary.